# Spring Data Rest: how to transform all urls in Kebab Case?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I want to use `spring-data-rest` to expose my repositories via an `API`. URLs are generated from domains name. Those URLs are camelized.

For example, considering domain named `EntityA`, the associated `url` and `rel` will be `entityA` (in camelCase).

How can I configure `spring-data-rest` (or what have I to override) to get `kebab-case` by default ? (for example, `entity-a` instead of `entityA`)

*I know that I can use @RestRepository and provide URLs for each repositories. But I'm looking for better solution. I want to use kebak-case for entities and searches methods.*

Comment: And with the new spring-data-rest versions?